# Fetching custom field on portfolio item

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I have a few custom fields on my portfolio item such as c_TrafficLightCost. but when I pass it in the fetch, to create my grid, it doesn't create a columns with the value of the custom field.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',


launch: function() {

  console.log('Our First App woot!');
  this._loadData();
},

// Get data from Rally
_loadData: function() {

  var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
      model: 'portfolioitem/deliverable',
      autoLoad: true,          
      listeners: {
          load: function(myStore, myData, success) {
            console.log('got data!', myStore, myData, success);
                            this._loadGrid(myStore);
          },
          scope: this
      },


      fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'c_TrafficLightCost' ]

  });


},

// Create and Show a Grid of given stories
_loadGrid: function(myStoryStore) {

  var myGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
    store: myStoryStore,
    columnCfgs: [
      'FormattedID', 'Name', 'c_TrafficLightCost' 
    ]
  });

  this.add(myGrid);
  console.log('what is this?', this);
  console.log(this.c_TrafficLightCost);  
}

});
```

What I want is for the traffic light to be a column in the grid

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Best regards Martin

Answer (score 0):

Remove `c_` in front of the custom field name. Try `TrafficLightCost` and see if that does it. I confirmed that the code posted in [this git hub repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/feature-grid) does not show values for custom fields (the column is empty) when `c_` is prepended to the field name. I think this is a defect.